# Hashing and passing arguments in vba

Tags: vba, excel, dictionary, hash

I have vba code were i need the count of cells that meet a specific string pattern. For example:

```
Sub WBR()
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Dim MinDate As String
    Dim MaxDate As String
    MinDate = InputBox("Minimum Date")
    MaxDate = InputBox("Maximum Date")
    If Not (IsDate(MinDate) And IsDate(MaxDate)) Then
        MsgBox "You should have specified valid dates!"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If CDate(MinDate) > CDate(MaxDate) Then
        MsgBox "You should have specified sensible dates!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Latency")
        [AE4] = wf.CountIf(.Range("O:O"), "Pass")
        [AE5] = wf.CountIf(.Range("O:O"), "Fail")
        [AE2] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("K:K"), ">=" & CLng(CDate(MinDate)), _
                .Range("K:K"), "<=" & (CLng(CDate(MaxDate)) + 1), _
                .Range("O:O"), "Pass")
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                
        [AE43] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("I:I"), "<>Duplicate TT", _
              .Range("G:G"), "<>Not Tested", _
              .Range("U:U"), "Item")
    End With

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("TT")                
        [AE44] = wf.CountIfs(.Range("G:G"), "Not Tested")
    End With
```

This code searches for the specific text and if satisfied gives the count of that in the designated cell.

I need to implement the same code for more than 30+ cells.

So how do I create a hash and pass the "keywords" here as an argument and if that condition is met then the count should be updated in the cell.

Comment: Should the count for specific text go into a specific cell? Like `SearchText1` goes into cell `A1`, `SearchText2` goes into cell `A2`? And is the CountIf counting on different ranges depending upon the `SearchText`?

Comment: Yes, the count for specific text should go into a specific cell. There will be multiple search text and if its met then the count should go into a particular cel. Example from above code: in cell AE43 the count gets added only if the "TT" worksheet col i does not have "duplicate" and col "G" does not contain "Not Tested" and finally col U has "Item"

Comment: Okay. But for all 30 cases is the column search the same? Just the output cell and search text are different? Because the code suggests different column searches on different sheets for different outputs for different search terms.

Comment: For certain cells, count are updated based on a single col search, and for different cells multiple col are searched and then the count is updated. Ex for single col search: AE4 ; Ex for multiple col search: AE44,AE43 etc

Comment: The basic thing you need is a loop where you can feed the arguments to the loop (either in another sub or directly in this one). However, the issue you have is you have to pass the arguments `searchtext`, `worksheet to place value`, `range to place value`, `column(s) to search on`. Because there are so many different types of possibilities it makes it convoluted to program. If you can group the 30 search texts into groupings of types of searches you can probably write something a bit more efficient. I was going to write something myself but its too complex and too late for me!

Comment: Understood. If you could give me a small example from the above code to group two cells, I could follow the sample logic and do it for others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am struggling to fully understand what your code is doing but you could make a makeshift "hash" by basically having a big string with some separators, and then split those separators at the end...

```
YourHash="Key_1:Value_1->Key_2:Value_2->Key_3:Value_3"
Split_1 = Split(YourHash,"->")
For i = 0 to UBound(Split_1)
    Split_2 = Split(Split_1(i),":")
    DesiredKey = Split_2(0)
    DesiredValue = Split_2(1)
Next
```

Something like that could work for you but I might not be fully understanding what you need.

Comment: Sorry if the code is confusing...my codes just goes to the worksheet mentioned and scans though a column for a specific string and if it matches, it will give the total count of the matched column in the designated cell. So I need to apply the same code to 30+ cells to perform this task (with different strings as the search conditions). So instead of typing the code 30 times, If the above code can be converted into hash with arguments and when the arguments (the string here) meets the condition, the count should be updated in the designated cell. @BYates

Answer (score 0):

I wonder why you are doing this in VBA to begin with. Why not use the worksheetfunctions you have in your VBA code already as normal functions in the cells you are placing their results into and use two cells for start and end date?

Comment: This is a good idea, but belongs to the comments section IMHO.

Comment: I have no idea about what you are talking as I just started VBA. Can you pl give an example of that so that I can understand from that? @jkpieterse

Comment: For example, you have this line of code: [AE4] = wf.CountIf(.Range("O:O"), "Pass") which is the same as having this formula in cell AE4: =COUNTIF(O:O, "Pass")

Comment: @ASH: I'm often in doubt whether to use a comment or an answer. In this case I'm really questioning the usefulness of VBA here, so I though it'd be important enough for an answer :-)